# Check on a dynamically selected radio button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently running Bootstrap with https://github.com/kflorence/jquery-deserialize and a modal. I use an AJAX call to grab the form from a php file and add it into the HTML form, deserialize data, and then open the modal. However, when working with a radio button, I can't use a separate jQuery script to check to see if the radio was checked. It always shows as false when checking with

```
console.log($('#travel_only2').is(':checked'));
```

However, if I attempt to output the selector itself with

```
console.log($('#travel_only2'));
```

then it will show as checked. How can I wait for the radio to get checked, or is there another option? Thanks!

UPDATE: also, I just attempted to use `$('#travel_only2').is(':checked')` in the console itself and it shows true.

UPDATE: I did away with the deserialize plugin and attempted this:

```
$.each(this, function(name, val){
var $el = $('[name="'+name+'"]'),
type = $el.attr('type');

switch(type){
    case 'checkbox':
        $el.attr('checked', 'checked');
    break;
    case 'radio':
        $el.filter('[value="'+val+'"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    break;
    default:
        $el.val(val);
}
```

});
Unfortunately using console.log(document.getElementById('travel_only2').checked); shows false then typing into the console once everything is loaded shows document.getElementById('travel_only2').checked
true

LAST UPDATE: There seems to be a delay since the ajax call towards the template had the script included. Instead, I used $.getScript into my main script to call the template script, and that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This is just pure javascript try this:

```
if(document.getElementById('travel_only2').checked) {
      // radio button is checked
    }
```

**EDIT**

Since that didn't work try this one:

```
 if($('#travel_only2').prop('checked')){
//radio button is check
}
```

Fiddle showing the functions I am using.

http://jsfiddle.net/bgLYL/

Comment: That didn't seem to work. console.log(document.getElementById('travel_only2').checked); showed false.

Comment: @ashin999 give my edit a try. It's strange behavior though. The vanilla js one should return true if it is really checked so it might not be set.

Comment: also false. Is there a way to wait for a deserialize to finish, or would that have to be implemented into the plugin? Cause I think it has one, but I can't access it since I'm working in a separate js file.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too. How is it that the checked value shows false, but logging the selector object shows true?

Comment: Logging the selector value _should_ return an object with checked being one of the properties of that selector and that should be false if the other one is showing false as well. And that is really weird if it's not...

Comment: @ashin999 Yeah it must have something to do with the plugin. I'll take a look at that and see if I can find anything.

Comment: If anything, I'll try to not use the plugin, deserialize manually, and see if that works.

Comment: I just tried selecting a radio and then checking if it was checked and it showed false http://jsfiddle.net/DYm54/